# exit status 1 'mcpButtonState' cannot be used as a function

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c++

I keep getting this error and I don't know why.

mcpButtonState is an array, and I would like to change one of its values using a line like this:

```
mcpButtonState(thisPin) = 0;
```

(it's inside of a for loop looping trough all my pins).
This is my complete code:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include "DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_MCP23017.h"
SoftwareSerial mySoftwareSerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
DFRobotDFPlayerMini myDFPlayer;
void printDetail(uint8_t type, int value);
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp;

int mcpButtonPins[] = {0,1,2,3,4};
int mcpButtonCount = 5;
int mcpButtonState[5];

int analogButtonPins[] = {0};
int analogButtonCount = 1;
int analogButtonState[1];

int potiPin = A2;
int soundVolume = 15;

void setup() {
  mySoftwareSerial.begin(9600);
  //Serial.begin(115200);
  mcp.begin();
  for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < mcpButtonCount; thisPin++)
  {
    mcp.pinMode(thisPin, INPUT);
    mcp.pullUp(thisPin, HIGH);  
    mcpButtonState(thisPin) = 0;
  }
  //ANALOG BUTTON SETUP
}

void loop() {
  int potiValue = analogRead(potiPin);
  int newVolume = (potiValue / 1023 * 30);
  if(newVolume != soundVolume)
  {
    soundVolume = newVolume;
    myDFPlayer.volume(soundVolume);
  }
  for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < mcpButtonCount; thisPin++)
  {
     if(mcp.digitalRead(thisPin) == 0 and int mcpButtonState(thisPin) == 0)
     {
      mcpButtonState(thisPin) = 1;
      myDFPlayer.play((thisPin + 1));
     }
     else if(mcp.digitalRead(thisPin) == 0 and int mcpButtonState(thisPin) == 1){}
     else {
      mcpButtonState(thisPin) = 0;
      }
  }
  //ANALOG BUTTON PLAYING
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[]` not `()`:

```
 if((mcp.digitalRead(thisPin) == 0) && (mcpButtonState[thisPin] == 0))
```

Note the use of `&&` instead of the word `and`.